# Firewatir not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, watir, firewatir

hi i am currently using firewatir.

But my browser opens but when it comes to the connecting to the site it fails it shows the home page of Firefox which is set by default..

error : **Unable to connect to machine : 127.0.0.1 on port 9997. Make sure that JSSh is properly installed and Firefox is running with '-jssh' option caught in : open_browser**

I have installed the Jssh also but i don't know whats is the problem.

Comment: Please indicate what versions you are using of the following: Watir, Ruby, Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Forget firewatir, it is dead. If you need to drive Firefox, use watir-webdriver gem. Depending on your OS, follow instructions in my Watir book: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads